# C++ Printing the member who got the highest in a result

Tags: c++, arrays

This is a problem given to me by my computer mentor and I am trying to explain the problem in simple words(I must remind you that my mentor has only taught me loops array structure. I cannot use class for this problem)

1. Take two matrix
2. Print the name of `n` students in one matrix
3. Print the `id`, marks in 5 subject of the students in another 2d
   matrix `(n*6)`
4. Find the student who got the highest in the total of 5 subject and
   print the student name with marks of each subject and his total
   marks.(i think we have to us a structure)

**For example:** The highest marks is secured by :

```
Name;
id no;
marks in sub 1;
marks in sub 2;
marks in sub 3;
marks in sub 4;
marks in sub 5;
total;
```

5. Then print the id and the name of the student who got highest in
   each subject

**For example:**

```
Subject 1  ID  name 
Subject 2  ID  name .....
```

I have being able to solve it fully till point **(3)**. but unable to print the person who got the highest in each subject ; and I am facing problem to print the person who got highest in each subject as I have to use many variables(I'm not using structure)

**What I have tried so far:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //making 1st array to print the names of the students
    char x[500][1000];
    int num, i;
    cout << "Enter the number of student's data you want to input" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "NAME LIST" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for(i = 0; i < num + 1; i++)
    {
        cin.getline(x[i], 1000);
    }

    //making a 2nd array to print the id, marks in 5 subjects of the students
    int y[num][6];
    int a, b;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "DETAILS OF THE STUDENT" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for(int a = 0; a < num; a++)
    {
        cout << "ID no of student " << a + 1 << ":";
        cin >> y[a][0];
        cout << "Marks in subject 1:";
        cin >> y[a][1];
        cout << "Marks in subject 2:";
        cin >> y[a][2];
        cout << "Marks in subject 3:";
        cin >> y[a][3];
        cout << "Marks in subject 4:";
        cin >> y[a][4];
        cout << "Marks in subject 5:";
        cin >> y[a][5];
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The data you inputed:";
    cout << endl;

    for(a = 0; a < num; a++)
    {
        for(b = 0; b < 6; b++)
        {
            cout << y[a][b] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    //finding the member who got the highest marks
    int s = 0;
    int largestSum = 0;
    for(a = 0; a < num; i++)
    {

        for(b = 0; b<6; b++)
        {
            s += y[a][b];
        }
        // check to see if we have computed a new larger sum and save it if we have.
        if(s > largestSum)
        {
            largestSum = s;
        }
    }
    cout << "largest sum: " << largestSum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will find that people will want to help you if they see that you took the time and effort to write a cogent, and legible question. The shown code lacks proper indentation, and in many places the indentation and the expected linebreaks appear to be completely gone, resulting in mostly unreadable code. Please take the time to properly format, and add logical indentation to your code so that it's readable, if you want to improve the chances of getting an answer. After all, it won't be possible for anyone to figure out your bug if they can't even read the code.

Comment: do you have a sample input and sample output? I don't quite get what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

```
int s = 0; <- s needs to be reset to zero in each loop
int largestSum = 0;
for(a = 0; a<num; i++) <- loop doesn't break
{
    for(b = 0; b<6; b++) <- b should start at 1
    {
        s += y[a][b];
    }
    if(s > largestSum)
    {
        largestSum = s;
    }
}
```

`i` is incremented while `a` remains constant and the loop goes forever.

`s` is not reset to zero, so you sum all the values.

The first index at `b = 0` is supposed to be student id, it should be skipped. Try instead:

```
int largestSum = 0;
for(a = 0; a < num; a++)
{
    int s = 0;
    for(b = 1; b < 6; b++)
        s += y[a][b];

    if(s > largestSum)
        largestSum = s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to go off of.

Note that I only made one matrix and put the `Student` objects in it.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> names = {
    {"Ralph", "Gerald", "Henry", "Jessica", "Bob"},
    {"Tara", "Tami", "Mike", "Loretta", "Jean"},
    {"Jesse", "John", "Carl", "Josh", "Abby"},
    {"Carson", "Don", "George", "Hillary", "David"},
    {"Micah", "Charlie", "Maximus", "Leonidas", "Xerxes"}
};

int main()
{
    time_t seconds;
    time(&seconds);
    srand((unsigned int)seconds);

    struct Subjects
    {
        unsigned int subject[5] = {};
    };

    struct Student
    {
        Subjects sub;
        std::string name;
        int id;

        Student() : name("nobody"), id(-1) {};
        Student(const std::string& name, const unsigned int& id) : name(name), id(id) {}
    };

    Student stud_matrix[5][5] = {};
    int count = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j != 5; ++j)
        {
            stud_matrix[i][j].name = names[i][j];
            stud_matrix[i][j].id = count;
            ++count;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "All student names:\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j != 5; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << stud_matrix[i][j].name << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "All student IDs:\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j != 5; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << stud_matrix[i][j].id << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j != 5; ++j)
        {
            stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[0] = (rand() % 100 + 1);
            stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[1] = (rand() % 100 + 1);
            stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[2] = (rand() % 100 + 1);
            stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[3] = (rand() % 100 + 1);
            stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[4] = (rand() % 100 + 1);
        }
    }

    Student best_student;
    unsigned int highest_grade = {};
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j != 5; ++j)
        {
            if (stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[0] > highest_grade)
            {
                highest_grade = stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[0];
                best_student = stud_matrix[i][j];
            }
            if (stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[1] > highest_grade)
            {
                highest_grade = stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[1];
                best_student = stud_matrix[i][j];
            }
            if (stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[2] > highest_grade)
            {
                highest_grade = stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[2];
                best_student = stud_matrix[i][j];
            }
            if (stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[3] > highest_grade)
            {
                highest_grade = stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[3];
                best_student = stud_matrix[i][j];
            }
            if (stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[4] > highest_grade)
            {
                highest_grade = stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[4];
                best_student = stud_matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "The highest scoring student in any one subject is: " << best_student.name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ID: " << best_student.id << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Marks in sub1: " << best_student.sub.subject[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Marks in sub2: " << best_student.sub.subject[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Marks in sub3: " << best_student.sub.subject[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Marks in sub4: " << best_student.sub.subject[3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Marks in sub5: " << best_student.sub.subject[4] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Total: " << best_student.sub.subject[0] + best_student.sub.subject[1] + best_student.sub.subject[2] +
        best_student.sub.subject[3] + best_student.sub.subject[4] << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    Student stud_sub1;
    Student stud_sub2;
    Student stud_sub3;
    Student stud_sub4;
    Student stud_sub5;

    unsigned int high_sub1 = {};
    unsigned int high_sub2 = {};
    unsigned int high_sub3 = {};
    unsigned int high_sub4 = {};
    unsigned int high_sub5 = {};

    for (size_t i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j != 5; ++j)
        {
            if (stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[0] > high_sub1)
            {
                high_sub1 = stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[0];
                stud_sub1 = stud_matrix[i][j];
            }
            if (stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[1] > high_sub2)
            {
                high_sub2 = stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[1];
                stud_sub2 = stud_matrix[i][j];
            }
            if (stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[2] > high_sub3)
            {
                high_sub3 = stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[2];
                stud_sub3 = stud_matrix[i][j];
            }
            if (stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[3] > high_sub4)
            {
                high_sub4 = stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[3];
                stud_sub4 = stud_matrix[i][j];
            }
            if (stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[4] > high_sub5)
            {
                high_sub5 = stud_matrix[i][j].sub.subject[4];
                stud_sub5 = stud_matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Best of subject:\n";
    std::cout << "Subject 1:\nID: " << stud_sub1.id << ' ' << stud_sub1.name << " Score: " << high_sub1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Subject 2:\nID: " << stud_sub2.id << ' ' << stud_sub2.name << " Score: " << high_sub2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Subject 3:\nID: " << stud_sub3.id << ' ' << stud_sub3.name << " Score: " << high_sub3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Subject 4:\nID: " << stud_sub4.id << ' ' << stud_sub4.name << " Score: " << high_sub4 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Subject 5:\nID: " << stud_sub5.id << ' ' << stud_sub5.name << " Score: " << high_sub5 << std::endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
All student names:
Ralph Gerald Henry Jessica Bob
Tara Tami Mike Loretta Jean
Jesse John Carl Josh Abby
Carson Don George Hillary David
Micah Charlie Maximus Leonidas Xerxes

All student IDs:
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24

The highest scoring student in any one subject is: Bob
ID: 4
Marks in sub1: 77
Marks in sub2: 67
Marks in sub3: 7
Marks in sub4: 99
Marks in sub5: 66
Total: 316

Best of subject:
Subject 1:
ID: 23 Leonidas Score: 95
Subject 2:
ID: 18 Hillary Score: 92
Subject 3:
ID: 19 David Score: 98
Subject 4:
ID: 4 Bob Score: 99
Subject 5:
ID: 22 Maximus Score: 98
```